# Making two sql fields require each other to be updated before changing

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm trying to figure out how to make it so you can't update one of the fields in my table without updating one of the other fields at the same time. I think that I have to expand my current trigger to do this and would appreciate any help offered.

The database is called **EmployeeInfo** and the table is called **tblEmployee**

The fields in the table look as follows:

```
EmployeeAddress | EmployeePostcode
---------------------------------------
15 Green Lane   |   S63 0NO
```

Apologies if the formatting is off. Thanks.

Comment: It happens that Postcodes do change... And people sometimes move to another address having the same Postcode.

Comment: If someone moves across the road (i.e. no post code change) you won't allow the address to be changed? Is it really better to ***prevent*** someone capturing correct data because there's a _mere possibility_ the data is incorrect? If that the case, just prevent updates to the table altogether then you can be guaranteed that any errors on the initial capture (such as typo on the address only) can never be fixed.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but at this stage I'm just trying to figure out how to actually create this type of validation so I can use it in the future. Thanks anyway, appreciate you responding.

Comment: @JohnGreen No, clearly you don't. This is not a case of you having picked a 'weak' example. You will ***never*** have a good reason to use that kind of validation. No matter what kind of mutual dependency you have between two columns, there's going to be a possibility that a row is inserted where one column's value is correct, and the other is incorrect. All your validation would do is make it more difficult for someone to correct the single column mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference New from Old.. Not up on mysql syntax but something like.

```
CREATE TRIGGER <TRIGGER> BEFORE UPDATE ON <TABLE>
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       IF (NEW.<column> = OLD.<column> or NEW.<column2> = OLD.<column2>)
               <RAISE EXCEPTION>
       END IF;
   END;
```